# What does ccpClamp do in Cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

google produced nothing, so I wanted to ask SO. What does ccp achieve?

Here's an example of ccpClamp being used in a method.

```
-(void) moveCamera:(CGPoint)pos
    {
        CGPoint to = ccpClamp(pos, cameraMin, cameraMax);
        to = ccpSub(to, cameraOffset);
        [self.camera setCenterX:to.x centerY:to.y centerZ:0];
        [self.camera setEyeX:to.x eyeY:to.y eyeZ:[CCCamera getZEye]];

        // update hud-level sprites
        [(HudLayer*)[self.parent getChildByTag:kTagHudLayer] moveSprites:[self getCameraPosition]];
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.0.0/_c_g_point_extension_8h.html#a9ece903bce575705f3e7fe2e81f011b0) doesn't explain what the word *clamp* means, but 
it is used to limit values to a set boundary (low, high).
In your example, it's equivalent to:

```
if (pos < cameraMin)
    return cameraMin;
else if (pos > cameraMax)
    return cameraMax;
else
    return pos;
```

According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clamp), *clamp* means:

> 1. a device, usually of some rigid material, for strengthening or supporting objects or fastening them together.
> 2. an appliance with opposite sides or parts that may be adjusted or brought closer together to hold or compress something.